# How to use bench filter for sidechaincompress filter of ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, benchmarking

I would like to use bench filter for sidechaincompress filter. However, it's hard to make bench filter work. Here is original command:

```
.\ffmpeg.exe -benchmark -y -i .\main_mono.mp3  -i .\sidechain_441_mono.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:a][1:a]sidechaincompress=threshold=0.015:ratio=2:level_sc=1:release=200:attack=30"  main_sc3.wav
```

I refer to bench filter's code and do it with like below:

```
int64_t start = av_gettime();

ret = av_buffersrc_add_frame_flags(abuffer_ctx_1, frame1, AV_BUFFERSRC_FLAG_PUSH);

ret = av_buffersrc_add_frame_flags(abuffer_ctx_2, frame2, AV_BUFFERSRC_FLAG_PUSH);

ret = av_buffersink_get_frame_flags(abuffersink_ctx, filt_frame, AV_BUFFERSINK_FLAG_NO_REQUEST);

const int64_t stop = av_gettime();

const int64_t diff = stop - start;

// calc by myself
```

However, I still want to get bench filter work in command line. Here is example I found

```
ffmpeg -i main.mp3 -filter_complex '[0]ametadata=mode=add:key=lavfi.testkey1:value=blahlbah[1];[1]ametadata=mode=print:file=metadata.txt[2]' -map [2] .\output3.mp3
```

Thanks a lot.